# Conditional Regex, how to extract a subset of a match?

Tags: regex, syslog

I have syslog strings, like this:

```
lwiod[2469]: S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628|0xC94F000|LOGON|STATUS_SUCCESS|10.10.19.10|10.10.42.40|COMPANY\USERNAME
lwiod[2469]: S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628|0xC94F000|LOGON|STATUS_SUCCESS|10.10.19.10|10.10.42.40|USERNAME@COMPANY
lwiod[2469]: S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628|0xC94F000|LOGON|STATUS_SUCCESS|10.10.19.10|10.10.42.40|UNKNOWN
```

and I have a regexp to capture everything I need, like this:

```
lwiod\[([0-9]+)\]: (.*)\|(.*)\|LOGON\|STATUS_(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(COMPANY\\.*|.*\@COMPANY|UNKNOWN)
```

What I also need that regexp to do is to give me USERNAME OR UNKNOWN in field 7 only, I don't want the COMPANY (which is an AD domain name), but I'm having trouble.

Field 1 would be S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628, 2 would be 0xC94F000, ... and 7 would be USERNAME or UNKNOWN.

Thanks!

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: It's PCRE based in a SIEM.  I should also clarify that I do want fields 1 to 6 as well, so I do need those.  What I'm trying to do is also get field 7, and only the username or unknown, without having to use a programming language.  These are syslogs that get sent to a commercial regexp parser, I have no way to tweak other than regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I guess you could probably use something like this?

`lwiod\[([0-9]+)\]: (.*)\|(.*)\|LOGON\|STATUS_(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(?:COMPANY\\)?(UNKNOWN|[^@]+)(?:@)?`

From your current regex, it appears that `COMPANY` is as is, so I assumed same. Otherwise, I guess you can use

`lwiod\[([0-9]+)\]: (.*)\|(.*)\|LOGON\|STATUS_(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(?:[^\\]*\\)?(UNKNOWN|[^@]+)(?:@)?`

Comment: this doesn't work from my testing backreference 7 has `USERNAME` then `lwiod[2469]: S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628|0xC94F000|LOGON|STATUS_SUCCESS|10.10.19.10|10.10.42.40|USERNAME` then `UNKNOWN`...which isn't right.

Comment: Good point, but that's only for the case of applying against a whole chunk of strings. If you apply it line by line, it will work as intended. If you apply it to a whole chunk, you'll need to add some more characters, namely `\n` in the negated class to avoid newlines. See [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/qK8lS5).

Comment: `\n` will skip the last line, because you don't have a line break on the last line...you'd want to use `$`

Comment: @abc123 Not sure what you mean. It's taking the last line fine for me... EDIT: See the link I have in my previous comment.

Comment: this is because you are using the flag `m` which according to your link `m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)`

Comment: @abc123 You can remove it, it will make no difference, try it. The regex initially had the anchors to test a per string basis, as opposed to multiple lines in a single string... Also, you are perfectly right. `m` changes the behaviour of `^` and `$`. But I'm not using them in the regex I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your language, simply split on pipes and grab the last element. There is no need to use a regex for this!

In C#.NET:

```
var myString = "lwiod[2469]: S-1-5-21-2071757552-4033313730-2397045981-3628|0xC94F000|LOGON|STATUS_SUCCESS|10.10.19.10|10.10.42.40|COMPANY\USERNAME"
var login = myString.Split('|').Last();
if (login.contains("\"))
{
    login = login.Split('\').Last();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to impose any language based logic.  These are syslog entries sent to a commercial SIEM, so all I have is regexp, and only one regexp to accomplish what I need.   I also need to capture fields 1-6

Comment: Ahh, that sounds very sad. :(

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the fields you are wanting.  To remove company you'll have to add more complex regex which i'll start writing now.

You can capture this into a back reference using a group:

```
: ([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(?:COMPANY\\)?([^|@]+)(?:@COMPANY)?$
```

this will get you all your groups into back-references 1-7.

backreference \7 is your username without company.

Comment: And I agree with yours! :)